# Unity3d rollback to previous state?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to make my Unity3D application able to "rollback" to a previous state so that the scene is exactly the same as it was `N` milliseconds.

For example, say I have a player which has moved forward 5 units. There are objects in the foreground moving around, such as a ball rolling... now imagine that I would like to "undo" 3 moves: the player should appear where he was 3 steps ago and the rolling ball should also move backwards in time.

What approach would I take here? I have thought to create "states", each timestamped with `Time.realTimeSinceStartup`, but [that property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) is `readonly`. Alternatively, I thought that I could keep track of frame count, enable `V-Synch` so that render time is at `30ms`, and rollback `30ms * n_frames`, but unfortunately, the render time is not constant, even with `V-Synch`.

Perhaps this is similar to saving the game and then restoring it? However, the save and restore need to be *very fast*, on the order of less than `10ms`.

What are my options here?

Comment: At a minimum you're going to want a *ring-buffer* of actions/states, that only tracks roughly the last (max-rewind) seconds.  Use `Time.time` for your timestamps.  Are you making a real-time game, or turn based?

Comment: Also, you can't change any of the Time properties as they are real-world clocks (and time doesn't go backwards in the real-world).

Comment: @Immersive Thanks. The game will be real-time, but I need to be able to "rewind time" to an earlier state and allow the user to follow an "alternate reality", so to speak.

Comment: Does it have to be time based? Or could you simply make it state based (meaning you revert to certain values you saved before)? Also a state based system might store multiple sets of values so you could still interpolate smoothly between them if this is even necessary

Comment: @derHugo If it were a turn-based game, we'd only need to know how many turns to roll back.  Since it's a real-time game, we need to know if the stored action/state is within the rollback time frame.

Comment: @pookie I haven't looked into this a whole lot, but it does look fancy and may suit you: https://ludiq.io/chronos

Comment: @Immersive things like `now imagine that I would like to "undo" 3 moves` to me sounds like a state based system. The "rolling ball"'s position could also be saved on each move. From the description I don't read that it explicitly should be time based instead of move based ... That's why I'm asking the **OP**

Comment: Seconding the suggestion for Chronos.